# Changed Time Machine disk and now I cannot see the previous one's content

Tags: time-machine

My question is; how can I see my old TM disk content?

My first TM disk was almost full so I have changed my preferences to backup to new HD.

Now I cannot even mount the first disk. When I click mount does not give a reaction.

All I wanna do is to see its content. I need them and I dont want to do something that may affect my files.

I can change back preferences to choose previous disk but I'm afraid of losing data.

Disk is in APFS format.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) There's a few details missing from your question, so it'd be great if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/322648/edit) it to add them in. For example, when you say the *Disk is in APFS format* do you mean the Time Machine disk itself? Also, do we assume you're trying to access the TM drive with a Mac running macOS High Sierra? If so, are these *old* backups ones that were made when your Mac was running an older version of macOS? Also, anything else you can think of that may be relevant?

Comment: [I can't see or restore from backups that are no longer connected](http://oldtoad.net/pondini.org/TM/E3.html)